# Does Google Chrome have a FoxyProxy equivalent?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Does Google Chrome have an equivalent for FireFox FoxyProxy?

Comment: According to today's page at http://getfoxyproxy.org/, the Google Chrome version of FoxyProxy is coming soon.

Comment: The accepted answer for this question is now obsolete, as FoxyProxy has a version for Google Chrome. Can you please mark another answer as accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Proxy Switchy!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/caehdcpeofiiigpdhbabniblemipncjj?hl=en) is pretty similar. Annoyingly, on Linux, it requires a Gnome or KDE environment.

Don't confuse it with [Proxy Switchy!中文汉化版](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bgfkhjmcnkmegdmagboackgipbdpomke?hl=en) (I haven't looked into it at all). Another option for Chinese speakers in [Switch Proxy](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fajkpbphiejhldakjboejnabfchhccnn?hl=en).

Comment: I'm on a Mac machine.

Comment: @3lijandro: Proxy Switchy! works on Windows and Mac. Sorry if my remark was unclear, I meant it as (if Linux then requires Gnome or KDE), not as (requires Linux and (Gnome or KDE)).

Answer (score 10):

According to [FoxyProxy's website](http://getfoxyproxy.org/downloads.html), they do indeed have a version for Google Chrome. You can find the extension [on the Google Chrome webstore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/foxy-proxy-standard/gcknhkkoolaabfmlnjonogaaifnjlfnp).

Answer (score 4):

Download section of http://getfoxyproxy.org/ now lists a Chrome version.

Comment: it doesn't work with Chrome on Ubuntu now

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Proxy Switchy! is not open source:
http://code.google.com/p/switchy/issues/detail?id=56

I found two other extensions, but they're not better:

- [Proxy Tool](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gjdgnkaeihfpoamjeeppmgcnpklpkagm) is also not open source
- [Switch Proxy](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fajkpbphiejhldakjboejnabfchhccnn) only works on Windows

Answer (score 1):

[Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm) works great for me.